# Can I activate a retail copy of SimCity on Origin?

Tags: simcity-2013

I don't have a CD drive so was wondering if it is possible to activate a retail copy of SimCity via Origin and just download the game from Origin rather than installing it using the disk?

Comment: i dont think so because its a retail version

Comment: and thats why i didnt put it as an answer i wasn't sure

Comment: So you want to know: can you buy the box at a store, throw the disk in the trash, register a code with Origin, download and play the game.  Right?

Comment: Absolutely.  Physical media is a thing of the past.  Get an origins account and the code, and go torrent the game files.  There's tons of torrents out there.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc why would you need to torrent it if it can be activated on Origin? Well, other than not having to use Origin, I mean.

Comment: @kotekzot In my experience, torrents download 3-4 times faster than direct downloads, as long as there is 100+ seeders.

Answer (score 7):

SimCity requires an Origin account and an internet connection so yes, your retail copy should have a product code inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

- Create an Origin account if you do not have one already.
- [Download the Origin client](http://www.origin.com/download)
- Enter the product key included with the retail copy of SimCity
  (either through the [website](https://www.origin.com/us/account#redeem-product) or through the Origin client **Games > Redeem Product Code**)
- The game is now unlocked, and you can download it with the Origin client.

Answer (score 0):

Origin is the delivery mechanism for EA games to receive their updates, as well as handle DRM.  This is much like Steam.

You have to install Origin to use the game, so essentially all you are getting at the store is a License Key, and some installation files for Origin, and maybe a SimCity downloader for the latest patch of the game.